# Find distinct count of common accounts between products

Tags: sql, distinct, combinations, google-bigquery

Imagine a table with two columns as follows:

```
Account_ID (integer)
Product_ID (integer)
```

Other columns are not material. This lists products bought by accounts. I want to create an output with three columns like so:

```
Account_ID_1 | Account_ID_2 | Count(distinct product_ID)
```

The result should have a combination of all values of Account_IDs and associated distinct count of common Product_Ids among each Account_Id Combination.

I'm using `Google BigQuery`. Is there an SQL method for doing this, or should I plan to code it in a full programming language?

Comment: I do not know Google bigquery, but take a look at [CROSS JOIN](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php)

Comment: so if both account have same `product_id` count() is 1 and if only one have it 0? Or is distinct from account1  + distinct from account2?

Comment: Do you want counts of 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me:

```
select
   t1.Account_ID, T2.Account_ID, count(t1.Product_ID) count_product_id 
from
   MYTABLE t1 join MYTABLE t2 on t1.Product_ID = t2.Product_ID
where t1.Account_ID <> t2.Account_ID
group by t1.Account_ID, t2.Account_ID
order by 1,2
```

Comment: should be : where t1.Account_ID < t2.Account_ID

Comment: Agreed. "<>" will give you one row with accounts A and B and another row with accounts B and A. Doesn't make sense in this case as the counts would be the same.  "<" will ensure you only get the A/B combination one time.

Answer (score 1):

Here I calculate how many product both account have in comon.

```
SELECT 
     T1.Account_ID as Account_ID_1,
     T2.Account_ID as Account_ID_2,
     COUNT(distinct T1.product_id) 

From YourTable as T1
JOIN YourTable as T2
  ON T1.Account_ID <  T2.Account_ID
 AND T1.product_ID =  T2.product_ID 
GROUP BY
     T1.Account_ID,
     T2.Account_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The BigQuery version:

(JOINs only on equality, while keeping the < in a WHERE clause)

```
SELECT a.corpus, b.corpus, EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(a.word) c
FROM
(SELECT corpus, word FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]) a
JOIN
(SELECT corpus, word FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]) b
ON a.word=b.word
WHERE a.corpus>b.corpus
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 4 DESC
```

Comment: This is exactly the query I need! Thank you very much. The query worked on samples.shakespeare, but my table seems to be too big for it. Error says :Shuffle reached broadcast limit for table __I0 (broadcasted at least 151001878 bytes). Consider using partitioned joins instead of broadcast joins .

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do a JOIN EACH (and if this is the answer that worked for you, why did you accept the other one?)